# Cannot covert.ToDateTime "Feb 29 2020 12:00AM" in c#.net

Tags: c#

I cannot parse the Date time text properly to the DateTime. My string fro parsing into DateTime was - '29 Feb 2020 12:00AM'.
The system throws error - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Error:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Put it as actual code in the body of your question. Same with the error message.

Comment: `DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("29 Feb 2020", "d MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);`

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToDateTime(String)` may not guarantee you the right `DateTime` conversion always. I recommend you to use `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` to convert the string to DateTime by specifying the format.

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("29 Feb 2020", "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I suggest `"d MMM yyyy"` pattern (*one* `d`): we don't know if `1 Feb 2020` or `01 Feb 2020` is a correct representation

Comment: Perhaps a note in your answer explaining why the OP's existing code works for 28 Feb but not 29 Feb may be useful.

Comment: @WK Puy, does this answer your question?